# Running a BAT Program in .NET

Tags: .net, console-application, phantomjs

I am trying to get Phantom.JS to run on a Windows computer and I have it working as a BAT file.  I can open a console window, launch the BAT file and everything appears to work.  That said, the output is too long for the console so I want to run the same thing inside of a .NET Console application.  I have tried numerous things but I keep getting an error 'phantom.js is not recognized as an internal or external command'

The BAT file itself consists of the following command:

```
phantomjs --config=config.json netsniff.js http://google.com
```

Here is my .NET code:

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C C:\\Test\\getpage.bat";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
compiler.Start();
```

Can somebody please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?  Thank you!

Thank all of you for figuring this out for me.  Here is a working solution:

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Test\\";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r getpage.bat";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();

File.WriteAllText("C:\\Test\\pageoutput.txt",compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Could you qualify the path to `phantomjs` in your bat file and give it a try? Sounds like it can't find an executable called `phantomjs` in the working directory while it's running under your .NET app nor under the paths in the `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: If your output is too long for a console window and all you do from .Net is start the same bat file in its own process, you won't gain anything.

Comment: I am using the RedirectStandardOutput to write everything to a test file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you specify the bat location as the filename not cmd.exe

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Test\\getpage.bat"; 
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
compiler.Start();
```

although I don't see the specific need for the bat file. you could just do something like:

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = DirectoryToPhantomJs + "phantomjs"; 
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "--config=config.json netsniff.js http://google.com ";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
compiler.Start();
```

the benefit of the second approach is you're explicitly specifying the location of phantom js so you *shouldn't* get the 'phantom.js is not recognized as an internal or external command' error.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  When you wrote "DirectoryToPhantomJs", I hit myself on the head (it hurt) and then realized that I need to use compiler.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory and set it to the Test directory.  That did the trick!